# Would be Drupal a good choice for my web app?

Tags: ajax

I have a 'webapp' that consists basically of making Linux command line calls; let's admit it runs the 'uptime' command and returns the output.

My app is currently built using CodeIgniter; it works fine, but i'd like to use the powerful features of Drupal that are built-in like users handling, views, imagecache etc.

My main concept is having a 'button' on which user clicks and then it runs the selected task (asynchronously, AJAX) and then shows the result (with jQuery).

I know of 'triggers' but I can't really think of having them 'do' some action once a 'button' (a link) is pressed, not a 'on node creation do ...'.

I just wonder if anyone has done something similar, and how.

Comment: You could also use Drupal as the front end, and send the ajax requests to code igniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both codeigniter and drupal are php frameworks. Can you elaborate more on what exactly you are looking for? Drupal is capable of doing everything a php can do. Also Drupal 7 has built in ajax support for forms. With additional modules like ctools, you can extend ajax functionality to any DOM elements.

There is [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) that is more powerful and extended version of triggers. Its the GUI version of if-else-then php statements.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the Drupal forms API.  The [Forms Tag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) contains several links to 
the form API list and a quick start tutorial.  *(Select the tag and click on 'learn more')*.

Using forms will allow you to collect information from the user, validate the input and execute the input.